# Two simple if-else codes in Python, should they not return the same value? Why each one returns something else

Tags: python, if-statement, control-flow

Two simple if-else codes in Python, should they not return the same value? Why each one returns something else.

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
  for i in word:
    if i == letter:
      return True
  return False

# This returns True    
print(letter_check("strawberry", "a"))

# Same function?
def letter_check(word, letter):
  for i in word:
    if i == letter:
      return True
    else:
      return False

# This returns False    
print(letter_check("strawberry", "a"))
```

Comment: It's not the same function, in the second you're immediately returning after checking the first element, so if the first element is not `"a"` (which is your case) you'll return `False`. The other function will continue until it finds the letter `"a"` and will return `False` if it doesn't find it...

Comment: No, those aren't the same thing at all. The second one will **always** return something on the firs iteration, because you have that `else`. You'd ahve to use something like `else: continue` but your first version is fine

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. The first `def` will return `False` only if none of the chars in `word` is equal to `letter`.

The second one checks only the first char in `word` and return `True` if they are equals or `False` if they aren't.

There is no need to loop by the way, use `in` keyword

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
    return letter in word
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `letter_check("strawberry", "a")` the 2nd time, the function returns `False` because the first letter of strawberry is 's' and not 'a'.